# Parsing multi-level XML with Google App Script XmlService

Tags: xml, dom, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble getting to the child elements to the `<result>` tag.

The code:

```
var xml = '\
  <document>\
    <currentTime>2013-09-05 09:47:06</currentTime>\
    <result>\
      <one>2013-09-05 09:47:06</one>\
      <two>2013-09-20 14:30:13</two>\
      <three>2013-09-02 14:12:22</three>\
      <four>2505</four>\
    </result>\
    <cachedUntil>2013-09-05 10:28:40</cachedUntil>\
  </document>';

var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
var entries = document.getRootElement().getChildren();
Logger.log(entries.length);
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
  Logger.log("%s -> %s",entries[i].getName(),entries[i].getText());
}
```

Running this code returns the following in the logger as I expected:

```
[13-09-05 13:54:18:815 EAT] 3.0
[13-09-05 13:54:18:815 EAT] currentTime -> 2013-09-05 09:47:06
[13-09-05 13:54:18:816 EAT] result ->                                       
[13-09-05 13:54:18:816 EAT] cachedUntil -> 2013-09-05 10:28:40
```

I get 3 elements and I'm able to run the `getName()` and `getText()` methods just fine. However, if I try to get the children of a specific element like `<result>` with the line `var results = entries.getChildren();` right after I define entries, I get the runtime  error "TypeError: Cannot find function getChildren in object [Element: ]". What the deuce?

I don't get what's going on here (obviously). `getRootElement()` returns an Element type. `getChildren()` returns an array of Elements. Where is `entries` getting turned into something that isn't an Element and is there a better way to parse this document? I feel like I'm missing something really stupid here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `getChildren()` on an element if has children. It depends what you are trying to do, but here is a simple recursive function that will pull what I think you want -

The key check is `elements[i].getContentSize() > 1`

```
function startTraversing() {
  var xml = '\
  <document>\
    <currentTime>2013-09-05 09:47:06</currentTime>\
    <result>\
      <one>2013-09-05 09:47:06</one>\
      <two>2013-09-20 14:30:13</two>\
      <three>2013-09-02 14:12:22</three>\
      <four>2505</four>\
    </result>\
    <cachedUntil>2013-09-05 10:28:40</cachedUntil>\
  </document>';

 var document = XmlService.parse(xml); 
 logChildren(document.getRootElement().getChildren());

}

function logChildren(elements){
 Logger.log(elements.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  Logger.log("%s -> %s",elements[i].getName(),elements[i].getText());
  if(elements[i].getContentSize() > 1){
    var children = elements[i].getChildren();
    logChildren(children);
  }
 } 
}
```

This will output -

```
[13-09-05 09:12:55:781 EDT] 3.0
[13-09-05 09:12:55:781 EDT] currentTime -> 2013-09-05 09:47:06
[13-09-05 09:12:55:782 EDT] result ->                             
[13-09-05 09:12:55:782 EDT] 4.0
[13-09-05 09:12:55:783 EDT] one -> 2013-09-05 09:47:06
[13-09-05 09:12:55:783 EDT] two -> 2013-09-20 14:30:13
[13-09-05 09:12:55:783 EDT] three -> 2013-09-02 14:12:22
[13-09-05 09:12:55:784 EDT] four -> 2505
[13-09-05 09:12:55:784 EDT] cachedUntil -> 2013-09-05 10:28:40
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. It took a while to figure out what I was doing wrong in the first place. getChildren returns and ARRAY of elements. Even a single element is still an array of 1. If I had replaced `var results = entries.getChildren();` with `var results = entries[0].getChildren();` I get the behavior I was expecting.